# Should I have the same DNS entries with my domain registrar and on the hosting server?

Tags: dns, vps, cname

I'm migrating away from shared hosting and had a question about configuring my new set-up.

I've transferred the domain to Google Domains. I'm using their name servers. And, I've moved the DNS records over as well.

And, I've transferred the site to a VPS at Upcloud. I have an option to add some DNS entries (A and CNAME--but not TXT) to the server as well.

Do I want to create the same A and CNAME on the Upcloud server that I use at Google Domains? Or do I leave them blank at the Upcloud server since they're already included at Google Domains?

Any insight or context would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A domain name has only one given set of authoritative nameservers, as published in the parent zone (the registry). So there is no two spaces to configure things, you configure your records only at your DNS provider (which can be your registrar, or your webhoster, or a complete separate third entity).